# A Python program that prompts the user to enter a sentence of at least 5 words

Tags: python, string, min

I've seen code on setting a max but can't find anything on setting a minimum and if its below it should give feedback that there is not enough words prompted.

Comment: Please post the code you've written and explain what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the

> .split()

function that creates a list with an item for every word in the string that you use split on.

```
sentence = input("Type a sentence of at least 5 words")
words = sentence.split()
if len(words) < 6:
    print("You need to type more words!")
```

So the length of the list that .split() created is how many words they typed.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(sentence.split(" ")) < 6:
    [Do something]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    sent=input('Enter a sentence of at least five words>>')
    if len(sent.split(' '))>=5:
        break
```

This script will keep loop till the user enter a sentence with at least 5 words.